# Does RabbitMQ contain functionality to deal with offline target nodes

Tags: rabbitmq, federated

Being new to the RabbitMQ I was wondering how to deal with an offline target node.

As an example this scenario:

- 1 log recording application that stores logs to some persistent storage
- N log publishing applications that want their logs to be written to the persistent storage via the log recording server.

There would be two options:

1. Each publishing application publishes it's log messages to it's local RabbitMQ instance and the log recording server must subscribe to each of these
2. The log recording application has it's local RabbitMQ instance on which each log publishing application delivers it's messages.

Option 1 would require me to reconfigure/recode/notify the recording application each time a new application appears or moves. Therefore I would think Option 2 is the right one, each new publishing application simply writes to the RabbitMQ Node of the recording application.

The only thing I am struggling with is how to deal with a situation in which the Node of the recording application is down. Do I need to build my own system to store the messages until it's back online or can I use some functionality of RabbitMQ to deal with that? I.e. could the local RabbitMQ of each of the publishing applications just receive the messages and forward them to the recording application RabbitMQ as soon as it's back online?

I found something about the Federated plugin be couldn't understand if that's the solution. Maybe I need something different or maybe I have to write my own local queueing system (which I hope I don't have to) to queue messages when the target Node is offline.

Any links to architectural examples or solutions are more than welcome.

BTW: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/easynetq/nILIKSjxyMg states that you shouldn't be installing a RabbitMQ Node for each application, so maybe I should resort to something like MSQM or ZeroMQ (?)

Answer (score 1):

From experience in what sounds like a similar situation, I would suggest using something other than a queue to store the messages locally, when offline.

Years ago, I built a system that had to work offline - no network connection at all - and then had to push messages through a message queue to the central server, when the laptop was brought back to the office.

I solved this by using a local database (sqlite at the time) to store my messages when the message queue was not available.

You should do something similar. Use a local database or even a plain text file or CSV file to store your messages when RabbitMQ is offline. When it reconnects, read the messages from your local file system and send them through RabbitMQ.

This is a good strategy to use, even if you do not expect RabbitMQ to go offline. Frankly, it will go offline at some point and you will have to deal with it. You should be prepared for that situation, and having a local store for your messages will help that.

...

regarding rqm node per application: bad idea. this adds a ton of complexity to your system. You want as few RabbitMQ nodes as you can get away with. Meaning, 1 per system (a system being comprised of many applications) when possible... with the exception of RabbitMQ clusters for availability - but that's another line of questions and design, entirely.

...

I did an interview with Aria Stewart about designing for failure with RabbitMQ and messaging systems, and have a small excerpt where she talks about [how networks fail](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQ3m3koSLWs).

The point is, the network or RabbitMQ or something will fail and you will need a solution like a local datastore so that you can recover when RabbitMQ comes back online.

Comment: Our whole idea is a decentralized system, so a central rmq would defy to point. Each application is running on it's own host, so I might still go for the rmq per host approach. What 'complexity' do you mean in that setup? As far as I understand the MSQM approach is just that, each machine has it's own send and receive queues...

Comment: if you want to avoid centralized message queue server, then rabbitmq is the wrong choice. i would look at zeromq: http://zeromq.org/ - it is a decentralized (brokerless) message queue